# Using getter function in require statement is resulting in an error

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

> I am using Remix ide to deploy the contract, Order of deployment is Test1 ===> Test2(address of Test1), Amount send for the function in Test2 contract is 1 Ether

> I am getting an error while calling the `createNewPerson` function, the debugger pointed me to `con.getPersonLogs(msg.sender).isAlive == false`

> Help is Appreciated

```
contract Test1{
    struct Person {
        string name;
        bool isAlive;
    }

    mapping(address => Person) PersonLogs;

    function setPersonLog(string memory _name,bool _isAlive,address _add) external {
       Person storage person =  PersonLogs[_add];
       person.name=_name;
       person.isAlive = _isAlive; 
    }

    function getPersonLogs(address _add) external view returns(Person memory){
        return PersonLogs[_add];
    }
}
```

```
contract Test2{ 
    address firstCon;

    constructor(address _add) {
        firstCon = _add;
    }

    Test1 con = Test1(firstCon);

    function createNewPerson(string memory _name) external payable{
        require(con.getPersonLogs(msg.sender).isAlive == false && msg.value == 1e18);
        con.setPersonLog(_name, true, msg.sender);
    }
}
```

```
status: false Transaction mined but execution failed
transaction hash:   0x5e8ff725419c9adc34177c69af4557a4c6819d82990c7f9517b6ac2bd28dc53e
block hash: 0x08269d8c9d0cb7c2f53601bb168b3d8590fa0a5360f05e040c45006a9129c8b0
block number:   11
from:   0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4
to: Test2.createNewPerson(string) 0xddaAd340b0f1Ef65169Ae5E41A8b10776a75482d
gas:    3000000 gas
transaction cost:   27632 gas 
execution cost: 6076 gas 
input:  0x6af...00000
decoded input:  {
    "string _name": "John"
}
decoded output: {}
logs:   []
val:    1000000000000000000 wei
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should use error messages. It's likely your require, but since you have not provided an error message it reverts without explanations.
You could use testing tools like hardhat or foundry that allow to use console.log.
Or split your require into two, to see which part fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the variable as `address` and then you recast it to `Test1` contract and this makes problems when interacting with the contract.

You should define the variable as type `Test1` and take address in the constructor and recast it into the constructor.

I will leave Test2 contract code:

```
contract Test2{ 
    Test1 con;

    constructor(address _add) {
        con = Test1(_add);
    }

    function createNewPerson(string memory _name) external payable{
        require(con.getPersonLogs(msg.sender).isAlive == false && msg.value == 1e18);
        con.setPersonLog(_name, true, msg.sender);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I still don't understand why my way of declaring the address variable and using it didn't work. Can you please explain what made it not work as intended ?

Comment: In Solidity, you cannot directly cast an address to a contract type.

When you declare the variable of address type it stored in storage as address, and you gived it a valid address too. you can't recast it to contract, since its stored as address.

In constructor you are passing address value not stored in storage so you can recast it (this is the official way).
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.20/contracts.html#creating-contracts

Of course they may be reasons in EVM itself, why this behaviour is not allowed, but I don't have alot of expereince in the core of EVM .

Comment: Thanks, now I get it